# How to implement a mux control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've implemented two different controls that allow a user to create and edit a filter for their data.  Both controls have a DependencyProperty called Filter that implements my IFilter interface.  One of the controls implements a RegularExpression filter, the other control implements a SelectionFilter (A list box where the select what items they want to filter on).

I'd now like to create a control that combines these filters into a *CompoundFilterControl*.  The CoumpoundFilterControl should allow the user to select what type of filter they'd like to use.
[image: CompoundFilterControl]

Ideally I'd like my CompoundFilterControl to also have a Filter DependancyProperty.  Depending on which Tab is selected, I'd like the Filter from the appropriate control to be selected.

I have no idea how to do this.  The only thought I've had is impelementing the TabControl's SelectionChanged event and attempting to Dynamically bind the appropriate sub-control's Filter property to the CompoundFilterControl's Filter DependancyProperty.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I would have your combined control also implement IFilter, and that implementation of IFilter just calls the IFilter interface of the control in the selected tab